# KVO on strokeEnd of a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift

I have two layers. `Layer A` and `Layer B`.

I am animating `strokeEnd` of `Layer A` from some value to some new value. And I need to also change something on `Layer B` simultaneously but it depends on `Layer A` current value of `strokeEnd` while it's animating. Is there a way I can observe `Layer A`'s presentation layer's strokeEnd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe `CADisplayLink` is the answer what you need.There're some code in my project,and just for reference only.

```
CABasicAnimation *progressAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    progressAnimation.duration = self.animationDuration;
    progressAnimation.fromValue = @0.0f;
    progressAnimation.toValue = @(progress);
    progressAnimation.delegate = self;
    [self.progressLayer addAnimation:progressAnimation forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateVipTagLabelAndBtn)];
    self.displayLink.paused = YES;
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

- (void)updateVipTagLabelAndBtn {
CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)[self.progressLayer presentationLayer];
CGFloat strokeEnd = [[layer valueForKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"] floatValue];
// do your work here

}

- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim {
self.displayLink.paused = NO;
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
self.displayLink.paused = YES;
[self.displayLink invalidate];
self.displayLink = nil;
}
```

Comment: your sample code definitely lead me in the right direction. Thanks!